# How to use fetch array in another php file

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a `$rowName = mysql_fetch_array($resultName);` in my login.php file. Is there any way that I can use this array in my main.php file?

THX!

Comment: Are you including login.php in your main.php? if so, then yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sessions` as HTTP protocol is a *stateless* one.

**`login.php`**

```
 <?php
 session_start();

 //..... your db connection and query code...

 $rowName = mysql_fetch_array($resultName);
 $_SESSION['rowarr'] = $rowName;
```

**`main.php`**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['rowarr']))
{
 print_r($_SESSION['rowarr']);
}
```

Comment: Then how to call the 'ftname' and 'ltname' of that array?

Comment: $_SESSION['rowarr']['ftname'] and similarly $_SESSION['rowarr']['ltname']

Comment: @Layla, first you could check if its a multidimensional array using var_dump and then if it is, you may have to access it $_SESSION['rowarr'][0]['ftname'] and $_SESSION['rowarr'][0]['ltname'] or else the above is the answer

Comment: @Layla, Try like what Prashant suggested , If you have a confusion do a   `var_dump($_SESSION['rowarr']);` and check out the structure.

Comment: @Layla, Can you post the output of `print_r($_SESSION['rowarr']);` on your question ?

Comment: @Layla, if you think the answer is useful, please mark the question resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use global variable. However, this is not advisable because it is not considered to be a good practice.
However, if you still decide to use it:

```
login.php
global $rowname;

main.php
$variable = $GLOBALS['rowname'];
```

Make sure you include login.php in main.php

Comment: This will work only, if `login.php` is included in`main.php`

Comment: Also make sure to include the login.php in main.php

Comment: @Log1c, I was just writing that point.. when you said it..